# To tell about a guess about a case in the past, why use "would+have+past participle" instead of "must+have+past participle?

Tags: meaning-in-context, past-tense, conditional-constructions, past-participles, conditionals

I have seen this sentence in an article on bbc, which is about **how people lived thousands of years ago**.

"***When this Neolithic home was built, it would have had a cosy roof of turf.***."

When I read it, I got confused. Because the fact seems as a simple past situation or guessing/assumption about something in the past. it simply gives information about a past event, eg **"when I was a child, I had a blue toy car.**

I have been making a lot of research on whether or not this structure **"would+have+past participle"** could be used instead of **the simple past** or **"must+have+past participle"**, but I could not find any satisfying explanation.

Almost all grammer contents cover this structure is used when we imagine the opposite of what actually happened in the past eg. "referring to a missed opportunity" (eg. "***if you had come to the party, you would have seen Tom*.")**,

But, in this case of this sentence, **"type 3 conditional"** is irrelevant. It is not an **if** sentence,  It simply gives information about how this house was like or was probably like when it was built long ago. Just like it would be If and old lady would want to tell about "how she was like when she was a child years ago. she would simply say **"when I was a child, I had long curly hair**.**. So **"when I was a child, I would have had long curly hair."** would be wrong.

So, my question is: 1-Does this structure **"would+have+past participle"** completely replace simple past sentences? or can be it be used instead of simple past?

2- If this structure was simply used because the author was not %100 sure about the fact as it was a long long time ago -so he wanted to make a guess or assumption, why did he not simply use **"must+have+past participle"** or **"it was likely that blah blah"** which must be used for guessing or assumptions about past happenings. Would it not have made more sense if it was like: **"When this Neolithic home was built, it must have had a cosy roof of turf.**

Comment: [I saw this article on the BBC.]

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/180481/would-have-in-texts-describing-history