# Which is right about a text on life 2000 years ago:"The house must have had a cosy roof of turf." or "It would have a cosy ..." or "It had a cosy..."

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, past-participles

I have seen this sentence in an article on **bbc**, which is about how people lived thousands of years ago.

***"When this Neolithic home was built, it would have had a cosy roof of turf.."***

When I read it, I got confused. Because the fact seems as a simple past situation or guessing/assumption about something in the past.

I have been making a lot of research on whether or not this structure **"would+have+past participle"** could be used instead of the simple past or **"must+have+past participle"**, but I could not find any satisfying explanation.

Almost all grammer contents cover this structure is used when we imagine the opposite of what actually happened in the past eg. "referring to a missed opportunity" (eg. "if you had come to the party, you would have seen Tom."),

But, in the case of this sentence, "type 3 conditional" is irrelevant. It simply gives information about what roof this house had in the past or what the roof was probably like when it was built long ago. Just like it would be If and old lady would want to tell about "how she was like when she was a child years ago. she would simply say **"when I was a child, I had long curly hair.****. So **"when I was a child, I would have had long curly hair.**" would be wrong.

So, my question is: 1-Does this structure **"would+have+past participle"** completely replace **"must+have+past participle"** or **"might+have+past participle"**

2- If this structure was simply used because the author was not %100 sure about the fact as it was a long long time ago -so he wanted to make a guess or assumption, why did he not simply use **"must+have+past participle"** or **"it was likely that blah blah"** which must be used for guessing or assumptions about past happenings. Would it not have made more sense if it was like: "When this Neolithic home was built, it must have had a cosy roof of turf.

3-If this structure is used in historical texts, is it not a must to replace all scientific texts on pre-historic times which was written in simple past with this structure **"would+have+past participle"**, because no writer can ever be %100 sure about anything that happened or must have happened 10 or 50 thousand years ago.? Perhaps any scientific texts (eg geography, history, anthropology etc) about how the world or life was like thousands of years ago.?

Comment: The lady _knows_ what her hair was like. We can only speculate about what a Neolithic roof would/may/must have been like.

Comment: Do not repost questions that have been closed. The other question already has reopen votes. See [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) which explains *If you see a question and do not agree that it truly is a duplicate, edit it to highlight the differences, then try to get it reopened by casting a reopen vote.*

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/180481/would-have-in-texts-describing-history/180484#180484

Comment: I still can't figure out the difference between these 2 sentences: "When this Neolithic home was built, it (would have had)/(must have had) a cosy roof of turf.."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"When this Neolithic home was built, it would have had a cosy roof of turf.."**

When I read it, I got confused. Because the fact seems as a simple past situation or guessing/assumption about something in the past.

---

My Reply

**the speaker is expressing an opinion.**

**"When this Neolithic home was built, it would (in my opinion) have had a cosy roof of turf.."**

would modal verb (OPINION)

used to express an opinion in a polite way without being forceful:

"It's not what we would have expected from a professional service". = It's not (in our opinion) what we would have expected from a professional service

Ref CED [WOULD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would)

Comment: If "would have had" express a an opinion, so what "must have had" expresses.?

Answer (score 1):

> 1: *If X was true, Y **must** have been true*
> 2: *If X was true, Y **would** have been true*

In many contexts the above constructions are equivalent and interchangeable (strongly implying that there would be ***no exceptions*** to the "rule"). That's to say, ***must*** in #1 makes it the ***emphatic*** version, and ***would*** is at least *capable* of carrying that sense.

But precisely *because* #1 is "emphatic", it's also more likely to be used if something about the context implies that Y might ***not*** have been true. In which case the speaker would choose to use ***must*** rather than ***would*** to emphatically ***refute*** any suggestion of Y being false.

---

It might help to consider the implications of introducing an adverb after the modal verb...

> 3: *If X was true, Y **must definitely** have been true*
> 4: *If X was true, Y **would definitely** have been true*
> 5: *If X was true, Y **must probably** have been true*   <=== UNACCEPTABLE
> 6: *If X was true, Y **would probably** have been true*

Where #3 and #4 (*emphatic* versions) are "equivalent" as pointed out above, and the unacceptability of #5 shows how they're ***not*** interchangeable when the sense is "non-emphatic, speculative".